# In Javascript how to display custom text when onbeforeunload event is fired

Tags: javascript, refresh

I want to detect if user tries to refresh the page, and my code is

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    var dialogText = 'custom text.'
    e.returnValue = dialogText
    return dialogText
}
```

however, when user click the browser's refresh button, it always shows
[image]

from mozilla's [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

```
Starting with Firefox 4, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string.
```

Is it possible to have custom text in the alert? seems mission impossible?

Comment: Check the dup I marked. In my answer there I cover all the browsers and what you can/can't do with each of them.

Comment: @Dekel, my browser'version is 55.xxx, so it is not possible to do that, right?

Comment: And probably count on trend of other browsers removing support too. Has been such an abused feature over the years

Comment: Thats correct. BTW, will appreciate a vote on my answer there :)

Comment: @Dekel, voted. thanks

Comment: You are welcome :)